# Scraping with Selenium and BS4

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

i am trying to scrap a table off this website as a practice - https://stats.paj.gr.jp/en/pub/current_en_n2.html

Problem here is, i am unable to print the full table. This returns only 1 cells from the table. Appreciate if any kind soul could provide some guidance.

My codes are below

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

path = "C:\\Users\Jun Hui\\Desktop\\Quant Trading\\chromedriver-win32\\chromedriver.exe"

service = webdriver.chrome.service.Service(path)
service.start()

url = "https://stats.paj.gr.jp/en/pub/current_en_n2.html"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)
driver.get(url)

link_element1 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//a[@href='index.html']")
link_element1.click()
link_element2 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//a[@href='./current_en_n2.html']")
link_element2.click()

page_source = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(page_source, "html.parser")

table = soup.find("table")
rows = table.find_all("tr")
for row in rows:
    cells = row.find_all("td")
    for cell in cells:
        print(cell.text.strip(), end="\t")
    print()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example how you can get all tables from the URL (as pandas dataframes):

```py
from io import StringIO

import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://stats.paj.gr.jp/en/pub/current_en_n2.html"

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:123.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/123.0",
    "Referer": "https://stats.paj.gr.jp/en/pub/index.html",
}

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers=headers).content, "html.parser")

for table in soup.select("table:not(:has(table))"):
    for td in table.tr.select("td"):
        td.name = "th"
    df = pd.read_html(StringIO(str(table)))[0]
    if not df.empty:
        u = table.find_previous("u").text
        print(u)
        print()
        print(df)
    print("-" * 80)
```

Prints:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                                                                   
1.Refinery Operations                                                                                    
                                                    
             Unnamed: 0                     Unnamed: 1 Current Week 18/Feb/2024-24/Feb Last Week 11/Feb/2024-17/Feb  Change from Last Week  Unnamed: 5  Unnamed: 6
0       Crude Input(KL)                Crude Input(KL)                         2765740                      2655588               110152.0         NaN         NaN
1  Topper Unit Capacity           Topper Unit Capacity                             NaN                          NaN                    NaN         NaN         NaN
2                   NaN  Weekly Average Capacity(BPSD)                         2839300                      2731443               107857.0         NaN         NaN
3                   NaN        Util. Rate against BPSD                           87.5%                        87.4%                    NaN         NaN         NaN
4                   NaN        Designed Capacity(BPCD)                         3230400                      3230400                    0.0         NaN         NaN
5                   NaN        Util. Rate against BPCD                           76.9%                        73.9%                    NaN         NaN         NaN
6                   NaN                            NaN                             NaN                          NaN                    NaN         NaN         NaN
7                   NaN                            NaN                             NaN                          NaN                    NaN         NaN         NaN
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                                                                   
2.Products Stocks（kl）                                                                                                                                                                                            
                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
         Unnamed: 0      Unnamed: 1  Current Week 18/Feb/2024-24/Feb  Last Week 11/Feb/2024-17/Feb  Change from Last Week
0          Gasoline             NaN                          1803404                       1802295                   1109
1           Naphtha             NaN                          1241808                       1202555                  39253
2               Jet             NaN                           750427                        755151                  -4724
3          Kerosene             NaN                          1672932                       1602863                  70069
4   Gas Oil(Diesel)             NaN                          1576961                       1552293                  24668
5               LSA  Sul under 0.1%                           335027                        298286                  36741
6               HSA   Sul over 0.1%                           421710                        409817                  11893
7               AFO             NaN                           756737                        708103                  48634
8               LSC  Sul under 0.5%                           676670                        688519                 -11849
9               HSC   Sul over 0.5%                          1167900                       1169686                  -1786
10              CFO             NaN                          1844570                       1858205                 -13635
11            Total             NaN                          9646839                       9481465                 165374
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                                                                   

...
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes tables aren't loaded yet when you're requesting the page informations. You should use wait until strategies to minimise this occurance

For example, you check the visbility of the table element (means the table is there), then for that table element, you find elements with the tag tr, which should return a list of table row elements. Then just loop through that and extract what information you need from that

```
table = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.ClassName("table-class-name")));

table_rows = Table.findElements(By.tagName("tr"))

for row in table_rows:
 #loop through table row to extract data
```

Just for a rough idea on how to implement it

Comment: thanks j, will look  into it,

Just to clarify one thing, referencing to "table" means the entire table in the webpage am i right? Bc there are multiple sub-tables within, labelled as <tbody>